# how to call a method from a matrix that takes the "bool" type?

Tags: python, matrix, methods

I have a problem with matrix initialization, namely with the "bool" parameter, how can I e.g. initialize a matrix and add it?

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, m, n, init=True):
        if init:
            self.rows = [[0] * n for x in range(m)]
        else:
            self.rows = []
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

    def __add__(self, mat):
        ret = Matrix(self.m, self.n)
        for x in range(self.m):
            row = [sum(item) for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat[x])]
            ret[x] = row
        return ret



m1 = Matrix(3,5,**? bool type)**
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What's the problem with the bool parameter?

Comment: @DMeneses yes, that's what I mean, I don't know what to enter in this "bool" parameter to call this object correctly

Comment: Pass `True` if you want the matrix to be filled with zeroes, pass `False` if you don't. It defaults to `True`, which is how it's used in the first line of `__add__`

Comment: @Barmar when I want to enter the value "true" or "false", I get an error for example `m1 = Matrix(3, 5, false)` - doesn't work   (for the tag - sorry, the mistake has already been removed)

Comment: Python is case-sensitive, it's `True` and `False`, not `true` and `false`. This is basic stuff, you need to read a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the third argument as such:

```py
m1 = Matrix(3,5,False)
```

Or using named parameters:

```py
m1 = Matrix(3,5,init = False)
```

Notice how in Python it's `False` with a capital `F` and not `false` like in some other languages.